# JAX-WS. SOAP response body <return> tag to custom tag

Tags: java, eclipse, soap, jax-ws, glassfish-4

I am receiving a deploy time error in Glassfish 4 when I try to deploy JAX-WS service with
a @WebResult annotated method. Below are the artifacts.

```
@WebService(name = "TestMartCatalog", targetNamespace = "http://www.testmart.com")
public interface ProductCatalogInterface {

    @WebMethod(action = "fetch_categories", operationName = "fetchCategories")
    public abstract List<String> getProductCatagories();

    @WebMethod
    public abstract List<String> getProducts(String category);

    @WebMethod
    public abstract boolean addProduct(String category, String product);

    @WebMethod
    @WebResult(name="Product")
    public abstract List<Product> getProductsv2(String category);

}

@WebService(endpointInterface="come.lets.learn.jaxws.ProductCatalogInterface",
        portName="TestMartCatalogPort", serviceName = "TestMartCatalogService")
public class ProductCatalog implements ProductCatalogInterface {

    ProductServiceImpl prodImpl = new ProductServiceImpl();

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see come.lets.learn.jaxws.ProductCatalogInterface#getProductCatagories()
     */
    @Override
    public List<String> getProductCatagories() {
        return prodImpl.getProductCatagories();
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see come.lets.learn.jaxws.ProductCatalogInterface#getProducts(java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public List<String> getProducts(String category) {
        return prodImpl.getProducts(category);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see come.lets.learn.jaxws.ProductCatalogInterface#addProduct(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean addProduct(String category, String product) {
        return prodImpl.addProduct(category, product);
    }

    /* (non-Javadoc)
     * @see come.lets.learn.jaxws.ProductCatalogInterface#getProductsv2(java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public List<Product> getProductsv2(String category) {
        return prodImpl.getProductsv2(category);
    }

}

@XmlRootElement(name="Product")
@XmlType(propOrder={"price", "sku", "name"})
public class Product {

    private String name;
    private String sku;
    private double price;

    public Product() {

    }

    public Product(String name, String sku, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.sku = sku;
        this.price = price;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    @XmlElement(name="ProductName")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the sku
     */
    public String getSku() {
        return sku;
    }

    /**
     * @param sku the sku to set
     */
    public void setSku(String sku) {
        this.sku = sku;
    }

    /**
     * @return the price
     */
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    /**
     * @param price the price to set
     */
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

The exception stack trace at the time of deployment is as follows,

> 2014-06-19T13:54:18.859+0530|WARNING: Deployment failed
>   javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: class
>   come.lets.learn.jaxws.jaxws.GetProductsv2Response do not have a
>   property of the name Product  at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointResponseMessageBuilder$DocLit.(EndpointResponseMessageBuilder.java:258)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler.createResponseMessageBuilder(TieHandler.java:212)
>     at com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler.(TieHandler.java:117)
>     at com.sun.xml.ws.db.DatabindingImpl.(DatabindingImpl.java:110)
>   ........... Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Product is not a
>   valid property on class
>   come.lets.learn.jaxws.jaxws.GetProductsv2Response     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getElementPropertyAccessor(JAXBContextImpl.java:985)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.db.glassfish.JAXBRIContextWrapper.getElementPropertyAccessor(JAXBRIContextWrapper.java:120)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointResponseMessageBuilder$DocLit.(EndpointResponseMessageBuilder.java:254)
>     ... 61 more ............. 2014-06-19T13:54:18.890+0530|SEVERE:
>   Exception during cleanup after start failed
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Manager has not yet been
>   started   at
>   org.apache.catalina.session.StandardManager.stop(StandardManager.java:934)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:6099)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.stop(WebModule.java:720)
>   .................. 2014-06-19T13:54:18.890+0530|SEVERE:
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Servlet web service endpoint '' failure   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5920)
>     at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:691)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1041)
>   ............ Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Servlet web
>   service endpoint '' failure   at
>   org.glassfish.webservices.WSServletContextListener.contextInitialized(WSServletContextListener.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:5362)
>   .................. Caused by: javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: class
>   come.lets.learn.jaxws.jaxws.GetProductsv2Response do not have a
>   property of the name Product  at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.EndpointResponseMessageBuilder$DocLit.(EndpointResponseMessageBuilder.java:258)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.server.sei.TieHandler.createResponseMessageBuilder(TieHandler.java:212)
>   ........... Caused by: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: Product is not a
>   valid property on class
>   come.lets.learn.jaxws.jaxws.GetProductsv2Response     at
>   com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getElementPropertyAccessor(JAXBContextImpl.java:985)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.ws.db.glassfish.JAXBRIContextWrapper.getElementPropertyAccessor(JAXBRIContextWrapper.java:120)
>   ............... 2014-06-19T13:54:18.890+0530|WARNING:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Servlet web service endpoint '' failure
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Servlet web service endpoint '' failure   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:1044)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:1024)
>   ............. 2014-06-19T13:54:18.890+0530|SEVERE: Exception while
>   invoking class com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication start method
>   java.lang.Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Servlet web service endpoint '' failure
>     at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:168)
>     at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
>     at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
>   ................... 2014-06-19T13:54:18.890+0530|SEVERE: Exception
>   during lifecycle processing java.lang.Exception:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start:
>   org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   Servlet web service endpoint '' failure   at
>   com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:168)
>     at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
>   ....................

Comment: What does the class GetProductsv2Response look like?

Comment: It's right up there, just below the interface.

Comment: No it isn't. The stacktrace contains reference to it (which is why I asked for you to show the code for it).

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. This is not my artifact. This would be something that Glassfish must have generated as part of it's Jax-WS deployment policy. My hunch is that there is a mismatch between the annotation that I am giving the Glassfish runtime and what it is expecting